# Предложение пропустить предлагаемую правку содержит лишний пробел

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При проверке [предлагаемой правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/108787) в описании варианта "Пропустить" присутствует лишний пробел:

[image: пропустить]

Вроде как пробел там захардкожен, поэтому, видимо, есть смысл переформулировать предложение, чтобы запятой в этом месте вовсе не было.

Comment: Кстати, с `Улучшить правку` там тоже дефект, но в отсутствии запятой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас всё вынесено в скобки:

> [image: всё в скобках]

Таим образом, проблема не проявляется теперь.